# You don't have permission to access / on this server after changing permissions

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am using AWS with EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18 and Apache2.

I needed to be able to upload files to my website using FileZilla. I got permission denied at first, so I did :

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www
```

(`ubuntu` is the user name to connect to the server on AWS with Ubuntu)

Now I can upload and delete files using FileZilla, but I believe it also caused the following problem when I try to view my website from a browser:

```
403 Forbidden 
Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Am I right? This is the cause for the error? How to fix it? I can't view my website anymore

Answer (score 0):

I believe apacahe doesn't have access to your files anymore.

You could do `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` to give back apache its access.

If you still want to be able to publish to your website through the `ubuntu` user and Filezilla you can:

- Keep `ubuntu` the user owner of the files but `www-data` as the group owner so apache is still able to access them.

  ```
  sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data /var/www
  sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
  sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
  ```

  This gives read/write access to the user `ubuntu` and read-only access to the `www-data` (apache) group.
- A more advanced way is to use [ACL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs). Apache is still the user and group owner of the files and have some specific access related to your website. In addition the ubuntu user can have full access to the `/var/www` directory with `sudo setfacl -R -m u:ubuntu:rwx /var/www`.

Other solutions have been discussed on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www/46371#46371).